# How to locate the end of the line in regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex
`in = in.replaceAll(" d+\n", "");`

I wanted to use it to get rid of the "d" at the end of lines

```
But I just won't do that d
<i>I just won't do that</i> d

No, no-no-no, no, no d
```

What is not accurate with my regex `in = in.replaceAll(" d+\n", "");`

Comment: `$` matches end-of-line …

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probably your lines are not separated only with `\n` but with `\r\n`. You can try with `\r?\n` to optionally add `\r` before `\n`. Lets also not forget about last `b` which doesn't have any line separators after it. To handle it you need to add `$` in your regex which means anchor representing end of your data. So your final pattern could look like

```
in.replaceAll(" d+(\r?\n|$)", "")
```

---

In case you don't want to remove these line separators you can use "end of line anchor"  `$` with [`MULTILINE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) flag `(?m)` instead of line separators like

```
in.replaceAll("(?m) d+$", "")
```

especially because there are no line separators after last `b`.

---

In Java, when `MULTILINE` flag is specified, `$` will match the empty string:

- Before a [line terminator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lt):

  - A carriage-return character followed immediately by a newline character (`"\r\n"`)
  - Newline (line feed) character (`'\n'`) without carriage-return (`'\r'`) right in front
  - Standalone carriage-return character (`'\r'`)
  - Next-line character (`'\u0085'`)
  - Line-separator character (`'\u2028'`)
  - Paragraph-separator character (`'\u2029'`)
- At the end of the string

When [`UNIX_LINES`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNIX_LINES) flag is specified along with `MULTILINE` flag, `$` will match the empty string right before a newline (`'\n'`) or at the end of the string.

---

Anyway if it is possible [don't use regex with `HTML`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1393766).

Comment: `"d$"` with the multiline flag is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

As Pshemo states in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21128264/2081889), your string most likely contains Windows-style newline characters, which are `\r\n` as opposed to just `\n`.

You can modify your regex to account for both newline character (plus the case where the string ends with a `d` without a newline) with the code:

```
in = in.replaceAll("(d+(?=\r\n)|d+(?=\n)|d+$)","");
```

This regex will remove anything that matches `d+` followed by `\r\n`, `d+` followed by `\n` or `d+$` (any `d` before the end of the String).

`(d+(?=\r\n)|d+(?=\n)|d+$)`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ZXbFNBVUrToOcSvI)

Comment: You can get rid of the first two branches in your regex; `$` covers all the bases.

Comment: @AlanMoore Unfortunately, not when dealing with `String::replaceAll(regex, replacement)`. `$` will only match the end of the String, not the end of a line.

Comment: @Daemon: `$` should cover all cases, when multiline flag is used `(?m)`. `$` will match right before `\r\n` or `\r` or `\n` (match before `\n` only if no preceding `\r`).

Comment: Doh!  Yes, I was assuming multiline mode, but I forgot to mention it.